# What would you call a person who is obsessed with being "normal"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word which means someone who has an obsession with being 'Normal', or someone who cannot bear to be different from other people, or similar. Is there any such?

Context:-

*A* lives in a western country, and always eats rice with chopsticks. His mother *B* scolds him for not eating like a normal person. When he cries due to the rather vigorous scolding, he is again scolded for not crying properly.

A suitable adjective for *B*?

Comment: Related: [One word noun for “rule-follower”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112905/one-word-noun-for-rule-follower) The description of the person is; however, quite different.

Comment: Is the mother, B, really a good example of what you're asking about? She might be viewed primarily as "[a nag](https://www.google.com/search?q=defne:nag)" -- she's not simply obsessed with being normal herself, she's obsessed with bossing someone else (her son), with getting him to conform to her norms.

Comment: @ChrisW I realize that, but no, I have no need of that word or synonyms.

Comment: Adding the example changes the question somewhat, so that some answers now look strange. I originally interpreted the question as "a word for someone who wants *themself* to be normal" however your example now means they want *their child* to behave in a "normal" way (whatever that is). In that case **controlling** (or maybe **concerned**) seem closer to the mark.

Comment: You asked for "someone who cannot bear to be different from other people", you got plenty of good answers for this. You then gave an example which doesn't seem to touch on normality, and changed it to be about somebody wanting someone *else* to be different. This late change completely invalidates answers with a +80 score! Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @AndyT I've understood the example as showing a mother who perceives her son to be different from everyone else around him, she doesn't want him to stick out or be noticed, in her eyes he does not behave like "normal" people, so she is the fanatical conformist.  I think the sample sentence is acceptable.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

How about [conformist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conformist)?

From Dictionary.com:

> **conformist**
>   [kuh n-fawr-mist]
>
> *a person who conforms, especially unquestioningly, to the usual practices or standards of a group, society, etc*.

EDIT: As user BerndGit pointed out, you could really underline the 'obsessive' with ***pathological conformist***

Comment: Well, it's close enough to what I'm looking for. If I don't get any better answers within a few days, I'll accept it. Good work.

Comment: Obsessive conformist?

Comment: I have to disagree because *conformist* distinctly lacks the denotation or connotation for *obsession*. However, I'm not downvoting because I don't think there is a single word in English that means "obsessive conformist".

Comment: pathological conformist?

Comment: I think "pathological conformist" works really well. It puts the focus of the obsession on the conforming, whereas "obsessive conformist" sounds to me more like someone who's obsessed with X and conforms to it obsessively.

Comment: Well, I lose. This is the best word for my purposes.

Comment: The word 'fascist' comes to mind from your context.  Not in the rigorous political sense but more in the common vernacular.  An example is in the the Big Lebowski during the sheriff's office scene ([contains swearing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_Vi0Z7an0A)) Basically the idea is that 'fascists' in the informal sense want others to conform as opposed to a conformist who is someone who is trying to conform personally.

Comment: You misunderstand that scene from The Big Lebowski. As used by Lebowski in that scene, a fascist is a thug working for an organized government that rules by fear and violence.

Comment: Obsessively conventional.

Comment: Oh, how these attempts at writing English pronunciation make me laugh.

Answer (score 14):

**Normalist**

> A believer in or proponent of norms or normality.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/normalist

Answer (score 13):

Your example helps a lot. You are talking about someone who is very **conventional**.

> **Conventional** -- Conforming to established practice or accepted standards [[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conventional)

The mother who scolds a child for not following traditional habits, when those habits are minor and have no bearing on modern life, is clinging to that tradition for dear life. She is stuck in the past, with **undue reverence for convention**.

Scolding a loved one 'for not crying properly' is also a *controlling scold*. Rather than trying to make sure that she fits in, she wants others to do so.

Comment: I completely agree with the conventional part, but the traditionalist doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 9):

More colloquially, you could call the person (a) *[square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_(slang))* (as opposed to *hip*).

Comment: If you're referring to someone as a square it's because they didn't go to the big event that everyone else went to, so they're actually not normal.

Comment: @Separatrix It all depends on who defines the norm. To be sure, from the hipster's perspective, not being (descriptively) normal is the (prescriptive) norm. Hence the paradox of the hipster.

Comment: Also that defines someone as normal not with being obsessed with being normal, which is a different thing.

Comment: @FrancisDavey Perhaps. But it is implied in the speaker's position that s/he finds the normality of the square -- excessive, if I can say that.

Comment: While this term has the correct meaning, it's quite outdated. I'd expect to only ever hear this term in the context of trying to make an anachronistic joke.

Comment: @henning Separatrix is correct, it's about not coming to 'the big event.' "Square" referring to a person likely comes from the idea that they're square because they aren't around ("a-round", i.e. a circle).

Comment: I think you are forgetting that it is actually hip to be square.

Comment: @Ghost Koi I was waiting for this. :)

Comment: It's worth linking it to the question that was inspired by this answer: [What is the origin and meaning of “to be a square”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378909/what-is-the-origin-and-meaning-of-to-be-a-square)

Answer (score 7):

I would argue you can't be obsessed with being normal and actually be normal. To obsess over it is to be weird in itself so given that, it will depend if this is coming from the 3rd person or not.

If you are talking about judgement from a negative 3rd person who is in fact likely the obsessive (with being not-normal, non-mainstream, 'unique') then they might use **Pretentious**, **Sycophant**, **Conformist** (as user1993 already suggested), **Townie** or **Beta** (both colloquial)

A more positive 3rd person may call them a **Social Butterfly** or **Amiable**

But, if this were a first-person assessment of themselves, they are more likely to say **Plain**, **Normal** or **Average**.

However, if this really is a person obsessed with the pursuit of normal, then they will probably see themselves as a **Weird** outsider (hence the obsession) and perhaps describe themselves that way or with the word **Wannabe** or **Nobody**

And in the same case, the negative 3rd person may (incorrectly) say they are an **Attention Seeker** (incorrect as they are trying to blend in, not stand out), **Insecure** or **Needy**

*I'm basing these suggestion just on observations over years conducting interviews and working in bars, events and other industries, which is why they lean towards colloquial use and are not necessarily correct use of language*

Comment: Yes! – To your first paragraph, [Pamela J. Hobart wrote a great piece at Ribbonfarm](https://www.ribbonfarm.com/2017/01/17/how-to-dress-for-the-game-of-life/) riffing on that very theme.

Answer (score 7):

A relatively new word from the world of fashion might work

***normcore***

> embracing sameness deliberately as a new way of being cool, rather than striving for “difference” or “authenticity.”

... is how it's defined in a [*New York* article](http://nymag.com/thecut/2014/02/normcore-fashion-trend.html) introducing the term.

(The inventors of the word [say the meaning's been changed](http://www.dazeddigital.com/artsandculture/article/19118/1/everyones-got-normcore-totally-wrong-say-its-inventors).)

**Normcore** is now in a journalism stylebook and [written up by Oxford dictionaries](https://global.oup.com/academic/news/book-announcements/woty14?lang=en&cc=de). And the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normcore) is quite good.

Comment: I've also heard "normalcool" used on internet message board going back at least 3 years ago and it seems to be used in a similar way except that it's typically used as a pejorative. I don't think you would ever find "normalcool" in any kind of print media though.

Answer (score 6):

I found that there is already a scientific word for that: "Normopath"

See: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/normopath

> normopath (plural normopaths)
>       A person who conforms excessively to social norms.

More details (in german): https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normopathie

Comment: I'm not talking about what B is, but that B *wants* others to be.

Answer (score 4):

*Conformist*, as already answered is a good fit. If you are looking for a pejorative synonym, ***sheep*** is an alternative.

Macmillan:

> **[sheep](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sheep#sheep_5)**
>   *NOUN* [COUNTABLE]
>
> **2** *INFORMAL* someone who does the same as everyone else without thinking about it

ODO:

> **[sheep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sheep)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2** Used with reference to people who are too easily influenced or led.
>
> ‘Don't be a sheep and follow the flock, do something for yourselves,
>   for God's sake.’

Comment: Not so sure this works. The OP seems to be looking for someone who is actively trying to be like others, whereas a sheep is (by the Macmillan definition) someone who does it passively.

Answer (score 4):

*normie* is a pejorative term in certain online communities referring to those who embrace mainstream culture to the point of being seen as 'unoriginal' or 'conventional' but in certain other contexts it could also mean someone who doesn't have any psychological or mental disorders.

From the perspective of the users of this word, a *normie* could arguably be seen as one almost obsessed with being normal.

Sources:

[KnowYourMeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/normie), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/2wtsaz/what_is_a_normie/), [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=normie)

Comment: I don't know what to say about this, but I don't think that a wide group of people would recognize this word. But +1 for effort. And coolness.

Comment: I'd wager to say teenagers and people in their 20s who have spent enough time on the internet would be familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, but they're not exactly a majority. Most people are the 30 something working, who don't spend that type of time on the net.

Comment: @marsh, of course, I did point it out in the answer.

Comment: @Nobilis oops missed that sorry

Answer (score 2):

maybe not quite right but I have heard of "mainstreamer" - its a group in advertising who are "normal" - ... maybe what is "normal" .. Mr Average  .. Ms Average ... Mr Median ! Ms Mean ... or "On trend" - in french "a la mode" ... not sure how to rephrase it if they are obsessive about it ...

Comment: This suggests... Uh., Passive normality, but I'm looking for someone who is *trying* to be normal.

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" is a subjective and relative term — something can only be described as such in relation to a "norm" or standard.  When you use the word "normal" in this way you may appear to the reader to assume that you both share a similar idea. Or you may sound critical or disapproving of the idea of normality. The words "conformist" or "conventional" sound more objective.

Your words "cannot bear to be" suggest that you may be leaning towards the less objective side.   "Obsession" can sometimes have a positive connotation( "passion") but more commonly denotes an unhealthy state of mind.

I can't think of a single-word term for what you seem to want to say.  These are some possibilities that come to mind, and they could be recombined with each other:

1. obsessively conventional
2. obsessively conformist
3. obsessed with not standing out
4. fearful of standing out from the crowd
5. anxious to be thought of as "normal"
6. over-concerned with following convention

Personally, I lean towards 1 and 2, although 3 might fit if you want to express some personal disapproval of the idea of normality.

Comment: I already used 3 in the question, and 1 and 2 seem to be different ways of saying the same thing. The rest are, unfortunately, overly long.

Answer (score 0):

"**Airhead**" or "**Basic**"? (amoungst other terms mentioned on this [Wiki Page for "Airhead"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airhead_(subculture)))

> "Airhead", also known as "ghetto prep", "popular", "Trixie" (in
>   Chicago),[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airhead_(subculture)) "basic b***h", or simply" "basic", is a slang term in
>   American popular culture used to pejoratively describe middle class
>   white women who are perceived to predominantly like mainstream
>   products, trends, or music[2] while at the same time fearing and
>   disliking diversity.

Comment: I'm not talking about what B is, but that B *wants* to be.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo `"Lohanthony, who made a ten-second viral video in 2012 in which he said "Calling all the basic b***hes, calling the basic b****hes, there's a new announcement: You're basic", describes basic b***hes as "someone who does what everyone else is doing and isn't their own person at all"` - The act of being popular and "basic" removes YOU from the equation... Might be a stretch, but I see "basic" as someone who does what's popular. That requires effort and attention to "being" basic.

Comment: Uh, sorry, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Worth a try and not a term I saw others use :)

Answer (score 0):

***Chameleon***

> A person who adjusts themselves to fit into whatever happens to be cool at the moment. Includes their appearance, their interests, their opinions, their personalities. Often referred to as 'scenesters' 'try-too-hards' or 'idiots'. ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chameleon))

(For me, the added "context" confused things....)

Answer (score -2):

One ought to call such a normalist "abnormal", however, it should not be done to their face.  This comes from the authority of a well-known blogger.

I would call them abnormal (just not to their face).

Comment: Your comment is funny, helpful, and brief. Placed as a Comment, it would fit better than as an Answer. You could move it right there. This site expects Answers to be more authoritative, whereas your opening "I would call them" is a signal of opinion. No disrespect meant.

Comment: Your comment is both a comment and an answer, although the question was not spoken.  It hurt my feelings. Feelings matter.  (Get with the milleniums!)

Comment: My apologies. I meant to be as gentle as I could as a reviewer charged with screening new members who post for the first time, unaware that we have standards.

Comment: Please take another look at my original comment. It starts with a sincere compliment followed by an explanation of the mistake. Third suggests you to take action yourself before you are embarrassed when monitors delete your answer. Fourth ends with humility. Again, sorry if I hurt your feelings unintentionally and you are unable to accept this apology.

Comment: "abnormal normal"   :)